# Can I use 2 passports?

Tags: uk, eu, south-africa

I am going to the UK for 2 weeks, courtesy of SAASTA. I have both a South African and a German (EU) passport. Would it be an issue for me to use my South African passport to leave OR Tambo, and then use my German passport to get into Heathrow (thus saving me the cost of a Visa)?

This is specifically for a South AFrican passport, mind you, as the country has some strange laws about these things.